# makefile which get also the name of the file compile

Tags: makefile

I need a makefile  which get also the name of the file compile
For example:

```
make foo

and the makefile should compile foo.c to foo.
```

This is my makefile. How to change it?

```
all: out

out: out.o 
gcc -g  -m32 -Wall -o out out.o

out.o: out.c
gcc -m32 -g  -Wall -ansi -c -o out.o out.c


.PHONY: clean

#Clean the build directory
clean: 
rm -f *.o out
```

Comment: That should work as is.

Comment: You posted two contradictory comments at about the same time. Do you still need help with this?

Comment: I though this working..but not.. some ideas?
make out work
but make out2 not...

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way where you can pass arguments to the Makefile but instead you can take advantage of variables to achieve what you want. Check the modifications done to the Makefile below

`NAME ?=out     #Default binary generated is out if you dont pass any argument`

`${NAME}: ${NAME}.o`

```
gcc -g  -m32 -Wall -o ${NAME} ${NAME}.o
```

`${NAME}.o: ${NAME}.c`

```
gcc -m32 -g  -Wall -ansi -c -o ${NAME}.o out.c
```

`.PHONY: clean`

`#Clean the build directory`

`clean:`

```
`rm -f *.o ${NAME}`
```

And you should call the Makefile by typing

`$ make NAME=foo`

`$ make clean NAME=foo`

Comment: if you give `make foo` then an error will be returned like `no rule to target foo` (here foo is not in the target list)

Comment: Thank u, but I think there is a way to do that because the is the  
requirement in my assignment. Someone know how?

Comment: What version of Make are you using??

Answer (score 1):

**Passing arguments directly to Make is trivially easy.**

Your current makefile can be invoked with `make foo`, and will compile `foo.c` to produce `foo`, because Make has implicit rules for handling cases like `foo.c => foo`; there will be no error even though "foo" is not the target of any rule. (At least, this is the case with **GNU Make 3.81**, which is what I am using.)

If you want to control the choice of compiler and flags (as in your `out` rule), there is more than one way to do it. The simplest (though not strictly the best) is to modify a couple of variables in the makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -m32 -Wall -ansi
```

Another option is to override the implicit rule with a pattern rule of your own:

```
%: %.c
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall -ansi -o $@ $<
```

If you want it to build `foo.o` in a separate step, you must split the rule into two rule-- and also put in a rule with no recipe to cancel Make's implicit rule:

```
%: %.o
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc -m32 -g  -Wall -ansi -c -o $@ $<

%: %.c
```

Further refinements are possible, once you have mastered the basics.